# How to use the mock object of the test class and call main method from the test class

Tags: mockito, junit4

In the test class trying to test the main method and not sure how to use the mock object here.

How to use the mock object orders to call the main method and it's methods inside the main method

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

```
public class Orders { 
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        Orders jp   = new Orders();

        jp.method1();           
        List<OrderItems> lstOrdItms =  jp.getListOrderItems();
        jp.processOrderItems( lstOrdItms );
    }

    public void method1(List<OrderItem> lstOrderItem) {
        .........
    }

    public List<OrderItem> getListOrderItems() {
        ............
    }

    public void processOrderItems() {
        ............
    }
 }

 public class OrdersTest { 
    @Mocks
    Orders orders;

    .....
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    ........
    }

    @Test
    public void testMain() throws SQLException {
         // Not sure how to test here
         // This will actually execute the main method instead of mock.
         orders.main(new String[]{});              
   }
}
```

Comment: The main method is static. Why would you call it from the object? I think the code from the main method belongs to testMain()

Comment: I actually did Orders.main(new String[]{}) which is executing the program. I just want to test it for code coverage. how to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the code from the main method into a test method?